# selecting records which meet a condition spanning multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, filter

I have the below data:

[image]

So each device_id can be under several services (B,G,P..) across the year and each value in the cell captures the number of months it has used a particular service. And the latest column captures the latest service it is using. This data is in a pandas dataframe.

Now I need to filter out the records for whom the number of months in the latest service is >= 3. In the example given only households 1,264, 267 should be selected and the others not.

The data in text format :

```
device_id   B   G   P   S   V   Other   Latest
1           0   0   3   0   3   0        P
2           0   0   0   0   0   12     Other
3           0   0   0   12  0   1        S
4           0   0   0   0   12  0        V
5           0   0   0   12  0   0        S
6           0   0   0   0   12  0        V
263         0   0   0   0   0   12     Other
264         5   6   0   0   0   3      Other
265         12  0   0   0   0   0       B
266         0   12  0   0   0   0       G
267         0   2   0   3   8   0       S
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you say that for only households 1, 264 and 267 the number of months in the latest service is >= 3? Is it because their row sums across columns B to V are >= 3? What is that rule? Question2: Why is 265 not selected? It's been 12 months since he got the service B, which is >= 3, no?

Comment: `number of months in the latest service is >= 3` You mean `== 3`? Because almost everything is >= 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use broadcasted numpy comparison, and find the indices for rows where their latest service equals `3`.

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
j = (df.columns[:-1].values[:, None] == df.Latest.values).argmax(0)

df.iloc[np.flatnonzero(df.values[i, j] == 3)]

           B  G  P  S  V  Other Latest
device_id                             
1          0  0  3  0  3      0      P
264        5  6  0  0  0      3  Other
267        0  2  0  3  8      0      S
```